# Vuex Property-Style Access Clarification

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

UPDATE:
How does one know from the documentation that virtual getter/setter is being used?  Is it just from experience working with JavaScript?  Is this just a common pattern within JavaScript?  Sorry for the newbie question

ORIGINAL:
In the Vuex documentation (https://next.vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#property-style-access), it defines a getter with:

```js
  getters: {
    doneTodos (state) {
      return state.todos.filter(todo => todo.done)
    }
  }
```

and then uses the getter with:

```js
store.getters.doneTodos
```

From my basic understanding of JavaScript, it seems like `doneTodos` is a function. So how come this doesn't work?:

```js
store.getters.doneTodos()
```

Comment: Vuex getters and setters are like virtual getters and setters in any language. See the MDN documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

Comment: [see source](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/blob/96a265a345c76ec7d0f81a115aef74b7eda89452/src/store.js#L454)

Comment: Thanks for the links.  If either of you want to post an answer, I'd be happy to accept it to close this thread. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on comments by @Daantje and @Lawrence Cherone:

Vuex getters and setters are like virtual getters and setters in any language. See the MDN documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

VueJS implements them here: https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/blob/96a265a345c76ec7d0f81a115aef74b7eda89452/src/store.js#L454